# Simplest way to create columns from variable's line content?

Tags: bash, variables, multiple-columns

Is there a simple way to create columns using BASH's builtin programs or GNU equivalents from variables - one variable per column - that are the result of listing directories?

var1’s lines should be in column 1. var2’s lines should be in column 2.

I’m getting partway there, but failing to get isolated columns per variable’s line content.

```
var1=$( ls ./somedir1/* | ggrep ‘matching filetype1’ )

var2=$( ls ./somedir2/* | ggrep ‘matching filetype2’ )
```

I’ve tried:

```
paste <(printf %s "$var1”) <(printf %s "$var2”)
```

creates 2 columns but with var2’s lines starting below var1s in column 1 and indented to the right and then continues in column 2.

```
paste <(printf %s "$var1”) <(printf %s "$var2”) | column -t
```

gives clean columns (without the indent) but the same problem - var2’s lines start below var1s in column 1 and then continue in column 2.

Answer (score 2):

Do not process the output of `ls` but expand patterns as arguments, and use `printf` to format the output of file paths expanded as arguments.

```bash
paste <(cd somedir1 && printf '%-40s\n' *.filetype1) <(cd somedir2 && printf '%-40s\n' *.filetype2)
```

`cd somedir1` Change directory to `somedir1`, `&&` and conditionally `printf '%-40s\n' *.filetype1` print formatted newline delimited file names that matches the `*.filetype1` pattern. The format also ensures a 40 characters column width.

`paste` will combine both lists into side by side columns.

Answer (score 1):

By default `paste` uses a tab character for joining the lines while `column` uses a space character for splitting the fields, so you have to specify the delimiter in the `column` command:

```bash
paste <(printf %s "$var1") <(printf %s "$var2”) |
column -s '\t' -t
```

---

Aside from that, is `ls ./somedir1/*` really what you want? Its shell equivalent would be `printf '%s\n' ./somedir1/* ./somedir1/*/*`

You could also get rid of the `| ggrep 'matching filetype1'` by using a more specific glob like `./somedir1/*.filetype1`

Comment: Or much simpler: `paste <(printf '%-40s\n' *.txt) <(printf '%-40s\n' *.png)`. Because @serveradmin shall not process the output of `ls`.

Comment: @Fravadona You make a great point! Yes, ideally or perhaps idiomatically, I should be using './somedir1/*.filetype1' as you point out. I did neglect to mention that I am playing with pipes as part of a project, and apologise for my question implying otherwise too. Your suggestion is the simplest approach.

Comment: @Fravadona The result of 

`paste <(printf %s "$var1") <(printf %s "$var2”) |
column -s "$(printf '\t')" -t`

is the same as my second non-working attempt:

`paste <(printf %s "$var1”) <(printf %s "$var2”) | column -t`

that gives clean columns (without the indent) but the same problem - var2’s lines start below var1s in column 1 and then continue in column 2.

Comment: @Léa Gris The result of 

`paste <(printf '%-40s\n' *.txt) <(printf '%-40s\n' *.png)`

that I have reinterpreted for my example as

`paste <(printf '%-40s\n' "$var1”) <(printf '%-40s\n' "$var2”)`

is the same as my first non-working attempt:

`paste <(printf %s "$var1”) <(printf %s "$var2”)`

that creates 2 columns but with var2’s lines starting below var1s in column 1 and indented to the right and then continues in column 2.

*I apologise, if by ‘indented to the right’, I implied aligned-right or right-aligned. I meant; ‘indented by 1 tab (from the default, left)’.

Comment: @ServerAdmin Do you see any `\r` or `\t` in the output of `printf '%q\n' "$var1" "$var2"` ?

Comment: @Fravadona I see no `\r` and `\t` in output from `printf '%q\n' "$var1" "$var2"`. (My apologies to you and @Léa Gris for my late reply - I have distractions but will keep trying your advice and working on this until I can mark a reply as an answer/solved, thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

column -t <(
  paste <(
     find /path/to/somedir1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "match1" -printf "%f\n"|sort
    ) \
    <(
     find /path/to/somedir2 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "match2" -printf "%f\n"|sort
    )
)
```